# MULTIPLE CONDITION IN SINGLE WHEN STATEMENT IN CASE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, case

I want To Specfiy two condition In single when statement
for example :

```
Case 
 When A.Contract_Payment_Frequency__c = 'MONTHLY' 
AND
DATEDIFF(A.loan__First_Installment_Date__c,B.loan__Disbursal_Date__c ) 
Between
 7 AND 35 Then 'TRUE'



When A.Contract_Payment_Frequency__c = 'BI-WEEkLY' and DATEDIFF(A.loan__First_Installment_Date__c,B.loan__Disbursal_Date__c ) Between
 7 AND 35  Then 'TRUE'
 

ELSE 'FALSE'
```

Im A Beginner CAN YOU Please hel pme

Comment: What error are you getting? That looks OK apart from the CASE not being ENDed.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix ANDs and ORs and control what should happen by using appropriate parentheses

```
Case 
 When (A.Contract_Payment_Frequency__c = 'MONTHLY' OR 
      A.Contract_Payment_Frequency__c = 'BI-WEEkLY') AND 
      DATEDIFF(A.loan__First_Installment_Date__c,B.loan__Disbursal_Date__c ) Between
      7 AND 35  Then 
     'TRUE';
ELSE 'FALSE';
end;
```

and less verbosely use IN

```
  Case 
     When (A.Contract_Payment_Frequency__c = IN ('MONTHLY','BI-WEEkLY') ) AND 
       DATEDIFF(A.loan__First_Installment_Date__c,B.loan__Disbursal_Date__c ) Between
          7 AND 35  Then 
         'TRUE';
    ELSE 'FALSE';
    end;
```